# Selectrow on rightclick in JQgrid

Tags: jqgrid

I want to be able to get Id when I rightclick in my grid. I have method ready for it my only problem is that I just need to able to select a row with rightclick.

How can I achieve this with the event: `onRightClickRow`?

Do I need to use the method `setSelection`?

Ive seen so many demos where people can use rightclick to select row but I cannot find any different code in their example.

Like this one: http://jsfiddle.net/nqneopvz/2/ He doesnt even use a `onRightClickRow` event.

Edit: whole question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I correctly understand what you want to implement. Nevertheless I modified your initial demo to http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/nqneopvz/3/ where I used the following code fragment

```js
onRightClickRow: function (rowid, iRow, iCol, e) {
    alert("onRightClickRow: rowid=" + rowid);
    e.preventDefault(); // don't display context menu
},
onSelectRow: function (rowid, stat, e) {
    if (e.type === "contextmenu") {
        return; // skip select on right mouse click
    }
    //...
}
```

I hope it shows how you can implement your requirements.

Comment: I have contextMenu so at the same time I open my contextMenu I want to select the row.

Comment: @Dollerup: I don't understand your last comment. Look at the demo http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/nqneopvz/3/ (see my answer). The row will be selected on both right and left mouse click. What is your current problem/question?

Comment: The fiddle can select with rightclick but my code cant. And what I can see the fiddle dont have any "special" code for selecting with rightclick. Does JQgrid support select with rightclick as default? But mess it up with contextmenu?

Comment: @Dollerup: Yes, it's so by default. The problem only that you write about "jqGrid" without specifying of version of jqGrid which you use and the fork which you use ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), which I develop and used in my demos, commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or some old jqGrid in version <=4.7). You used in your original demo the latest free jqGrid. It should have no problem with selection, but your demo starts inline editing of right mouse click too. It's unclear what behavior you need exactly.

Comment: @Dollerup: you wrote "The fiddle can select with rightclick but my code cant". You should verify *which version of jqGrid you use in your code*. I recommend you to use free jqGrid 4.13.3 from CDN. See [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs) for details. You need just change 2-3 lines of your HTML page to force loading of free jqGrid 4.13.3. You will see whether the problem will be fixed after that.

Comment: Im using 4.6.0. My only behavior I need is to select the row I rightclick and open the Contextmenu. Do I need a newer version for it to work? so I can use selrow.

Comment: @Dollerup: Did you made the test with free jqGrid 4.13.3?

Comment: @Dollerup: If you want that I help you then **you should provide the demo, which reproduces the problem**. I created the demo, which have no problem. It does exactly what you describes. Thus your real application do not what you described or your last tests was incorrect (for example you could use old web browser cache instead of usage new sources).

Comment: Ur demo dont have a contextmenu.

Comment: @Dollerup: Sorry, but I can't follow you. What is your current question/your current problem? Your original question was: selection of row on right mouse click. Is it work? If it work, but your application for example **unselect** previously selected row inside of *your implementation of context menu*, then it's absolutely another problem. You should describe *what you (your program) do exactly*.

Comment: @Dollerup: It's really difficult to discuss the code where I have no idea what you do. Do you use `multiselect: true` option? If you don't use it that free jqGrid have one more option `singleSelectClickMode: "toggle"`, which can be change to `singleSelectClickMode: "selectonly"` to prevent deselection of previously selected rows by clicking. Probably the option helps you. **I can only guess, till you provides the demo, which reproduces the problem**.

Comment: My rightclick does not select a row. Thats my problem. I wonder if the problem is because I run a contextmenu on the event "onRightClickRow". Because when I watch other people demos they can select a row with rightclick. Notice! The demo I linked is not my code I just wanted to give you an example that they can use rightclick to select a row. And what I can see they dont have something special on the event "onRightClickRow" that make it possible to select with rightclick. So again my problem is that I cant select a row with rightclick. Is there any function out there that make it possible?

Comment: @Dollerup: Could you guess, which number I said during writing the sentence? I believe you can't. In the same way I can't guess what's wrong thing you do in your code if you don't provide the demo, which reproduce the problem. You real code create context menu in some way, which I don't know. I repeat, that I can only guess, that the code is the origin of your problem and the code *deselect* the row previously selected by jqGrid.

Comment: I dont know why you need my code? All I ask for is a function that select the row I rightclick.

Comment: @Dollerup: [My original demo](http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/nqneopvz/3/) demonstrates that `onRightClickRow` don't prevent selection of rows. [The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/createContexMenuFromNavigatorButtons1.htm) is just an example how one can use context menu. You see that no problem with selection exist in the context menu too. Thus there are no general problem with selection of rows on right mouse click, but there are some problem in *your code* only.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nqneopvz/18/ I made a fiddle now didnt get the contextmenu to work but as you u can see rightclick dont work to select a row.

Comment: @Dollerup: Your last demo uses `multiselect: true` option. jqGrid select the row by default only if `multiselect: false`. I asked you before, whether you use the option (see my previous comments). You can add `$(this).jqGrid("setSelection", rowid, false, e);` inside of `onRightClickRow` for example. You should be carefully because the `setSelection` *inverts* the current selection. Thus if you don't need to unselect the row if it's already selected, then you should test whether the rowid is already selected (it's in `selarrrow`). See http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/nqneopvz/19/

Comment: @Dollerup: I commented some lines inside of `onRightClickRow` because there are absolutely wrong. One should never register event handlers inside of some other event handle. You old code registered `$(".addBtn").click` for example. On the first `onRightClickRow` it register the event handler. On the next click it register the same handler **once more**. It means that the event handler will be called **twice** on click on `$(".addBtn")`. On the next processing `onRightClickRow` it will register the same handler the 3-d time and the event handler will be called 3 times on one click....

Comment: How do you mean I should do it then. I did it for rowid.

Comment: @Dollerup: The code fragment which you posed don't contain any HTML element with the `class="addBtn"` or `class="table_list_1"`. Thus `$(".addBtn")` and `$('.table_list_1')` do nothing. If you mean `$('#table_list_1')` instead of `$('.table_list_1')` then you could move `.contextmenu({target:'#context-menu'});` **outside** of callback `onRightClickRow`. It will be called **once**. The event handler stay working till one call `unbind` or one destroys the element (for example `<table id="table_list_1">...</table>`)